# what is the preferred way of writing scaleable multi column layouts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a webpage with 3 columns and only looks good on full size screens. I'm about to write some major updates to make my website mobile friendly. The rest of my website i have no qualms about updating, the upgrades will be straight forward, but i have no idea how i am going to tackle my 3 column table layout. in order to make it mobile i am going to have to take the three columns and move the contents into a singular column.

to accomplish this can it be achieved purely through html & css? or is it something that will involve javascript? doing it in javascript will be fine but if there is a way to do it in CSS i would prefer to start there.

```
  <table id="resource_manager">
        <tr> <!--Row #1-->
          <td colspan="3">
            <h1 class="center_text">Notable Ministries</h1>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!--Row #2-->
          <td colspan="2" class="center_text">
            <p style="text-align: left">
              My purpose for putting this together is mainly because friends ask me where they can get more information on something, it's always nice to be able
              to point someone in the right direction to get answers.
              <br><br>
              All resources here should be publicly accessible, mostly via youtube or directly from the persons web page. Please notify me if any links are broken.
              <br><br>
              <h2 style="text-align: left">Ephesians 4:11-16</h2>
                <p style="text-align: left">
                And He Himself gave some to be apostles, some prophets, some evangelists, and some pastors and teachers, for the equipping of the saints for
                the work of ministry, for the edifying of the body of Christ, till we all come to the unity of the faith and of the knowledge of the Son of God, to
                a perfect man, to the measure of the stature of the fullness of Christ; that we should no longer be children, tossed to and fro and carried about
                with every wind of doctrine, by the trickery of men, in the cunning craftiness of deceitful plotting, but, speaking the truth in love, may grow up
                in all things into Him who is the head—Christ— from whom the whole body, joined and knit together by what every joint supplies, according to the
                effective working by which every part does its share, causes growth of the body for the edifying of itself in love.
                </p>
            </p>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="resource_row_image"> <!--Row #3-->
          <td class="cell_size"> <!--Cell 1 Keith Moore-->
            <a href="http://www.moorelife.org/freedownloads-serieslist.php?" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/resources/keith_moore.jpg" alt="keith moore" class="resource_image">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="cell_size"> <!--Cell 2 Kenneth Hagin-->
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIXcY2izjpDgROo3MRlAU2MJSyjthXLLc" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/resources/kenneth_hagin.jpg" alt="kenneth hagin" class="resource_image">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="cell_size"> <!--Cell 3 Bill Johnson-->
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEtP4XPKdli585uNfIU8WNRYawCusmEYK" target="_blank">
              <img src="img/resources/bill_johnson.jpg" alt="bill johnson" class="resource_image">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
          <tr class="resource_row_text"> <!--Row #4-->
            <td class="cell_size"> <!--Cell 1 Keith Moore-->
              <h2>Keith Moore</h2>
              Teacher/Pastor, I reffer to Keith as my "bible college experience," he has 30+ years
              of free audio and video available on any and every subject.
            </td>
            <td class="cell_size"> <!--Cell 2 Kenneth Hagin-->
              <h2>Kenneth Hagin</h2>
              Prophet, with nearly 70 years of ministry under his belt, Hagin most commonly preached on the subject of faith in Gods word.
            </td>
            <td class="cell_size"> <!--Cell 3 Bill Johnson-->
              <h2>Bill Johnson</h2>
                Apostle/Pastor, Bill pastors a church in Redding California named Bethel Church, the church is most known for miracles, signs and wonders.
            </td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: You can try bootstrap grid layout  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [Flexbox](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/). 
[Here](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/YwNPPM?editors=110) is a simple 3 column layout.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">COL 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">COL 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">COL 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex: row nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see little HTML and CSS is needed in order to create this layout. If you would like to change the 3 column layout when viewed on a phone you can use [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks like Bootstrap (getbootstrap.com - my personal preference) or Foundation (foundation.zurb.com) would solve all of this for you.

If you're not looking to use an external framework, you can use the @media query in your CSS file, like this:

```
/* on any screen smaller than 480px */ 

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  .cell-size {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This way, you can specify exactly how it will look on particular screen sizes. Here's more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way these days is to use Twitter's 'Bootstrap3' framework. It has a grid layout system which is responsive.

Here is the code that you gave done in bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/f9prc0ad/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2>
                    Notable Ministries
                </h2>
                <p>
                    My purpose for putting this together is mainly because friends ask me where they can get more information on something, it's always nice to be able
              to point someone in the right direction to get answers.      
                </p>
                <p>
                    All resources here should be publicly accessible, mostly via youtube or directly from the persons web page. Please notify me if any links are broken.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-md-12">
                <blockquote>
                <p>
                    And He Himself gave some to be apostles, some prophets, some evangelists, and some pastors and teachers, for the equipping of the saints for
                the work of ministry, for the edifying of the body of Christ, till we all come to the unity of the faith and of the knowledge of the Son of God, to
                a perfect man, to the measure of the stature of the fullness of Christ; that we should no longer be children, tossed to and fro and carried about
                with every wind of doctrine, by the trickery of men, in the cunning craftiness of deceitful plotting, but, speaking the truth in love, may grow up
                in all things into Him who is the head—Christ— from whom the whole body, joined and knit together by what every joint supplies, according to the
                effective working by which every part does its share, causes growth of the body for the edifying of itself in love.
                </p> <small>Ephesians <cite>4:11-16</cite></small>
            </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="media">
                 <a href="http://www.moorelife.org/freedownloads-serieslist.php?" class="pull-left"><img alt="Bootstrap Media Preview" src="http://www.godpreach.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/keith-moore.jpg" class="media-object" width="200px" /></a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        Keith Moore
                    </h4> Teacher/Pastor, I reffer to Keith as my "bible college experience," he has 30+ years
              of free audio and video available on any and every subject.
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="media">
                 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIXcY2izjpDgROo3MRlAU2MJSyjthXLLc" class="pull-left"><img alt="Bootstrap Media Preview" src="http://www.harrisonhouse.com/client/client_images/authors/1110large.jpg" class="media-object" width="200px"/></a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        Kenneth Hagin
                    </h4> Prophet, with nearly 70 years of ministry under his belt, Hagin most commonly preached on the subject of faith in Gods word.
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="media">
                 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEtP4XPKdli585uNfIU8WNRYawCusmEYK" class="pull-left"><img alt="Bootstrap Media Preview" src="http://www.hisevents.com/assets/images/content/cache/d6c1d9cbd289fb0a70bb3c6aeb1b6c93de057ef1.jpg" class="media-object" width="200px" /></a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        Bill Johnson
                    </h4> Apostle/Pastor, Bill pastors a church in Redding California named Bethel Church, the church is most known for miracles, signs and wonders.
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how it's all in a column when the screensize is small and when you zoom out to give a bigger screen size you see it changes to 3 columns.